# My 2011 Honda Pilot hesitates/shudders when starting forward from a complete stop. Any thoughts on cause?

Tags: honda, pilot

My 2011 Honda Pilot shudders/hesitates when moving forward from a stop.  Any thoughts on the cause?

It does not happen all of the time, but when it does occur the Pilot is going between 20 and 30 mph. Most frequently happens when moving forward from a stop. One mechanic said it was the eco boost resetting and was normal. This is not normal because it has not always occurred. The pilot has 93,000 miles and I have had the vehicle since March, 2016. Hope this info helps.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for contributing a question! As it stands, there is not enough information here for more than general suggestions and lucky guesses. Can you say more about what's happening? For example when did you start noticing it? What's changed recently? Are there things that make it better or worse? What transmission do you have (manual or automatic)?

Comment: Does it happen all the time? Only when the car is cold? Does it matter how heavily you try to accelerate? Did it appear all at once or is it getting worse? Spend some time giving us real details.